# How to array file's name from folder?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create autocomplete from 'image' folder. I have more than 50 images in 'image' folder. How to array all images name from the folder?

search.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Load sample data
 */
include 'data.php';

/*
 * Results array
 */
$results = array();

/*
 * Autocomplete formatter
 */
function autocomplete_format($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result[0] . '|' . $result[1] . "\n";
    }
}

/*
 * Search for term if it is given
 */
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = strtolower($_GET['q']);
    if ($q) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
                $results[] = array($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Output format
 */
$output = 'autocomplete';
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
    $output = strtolower($_GET['output']);
}

/*
 * Output results
 */
if ($output === 'json') {
    echo json_encode($results);
} else {
    echo autocomplete_format($results);
}
```

data.php

```
    <?php
        $data = array( /*
 * image_name
 */ );
```

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/jquery.autocomplete.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $("#ac5").autocomplete('search.php', {
            minChars: 1,
            useDelimiter: true,
            selectFirst: true,
            autoFill: true,
        });

    </script>

    <form>
            <input type="text" id="ac5">
        </form>
```

I using jquery.autocomplete.js and Not working...

Comment: What? What do you want?

Comment: Do you want to put all filenames from a directory into an array? If so then use `scandir`    For example `$files = scandir("directory");`

Comment: Is possible to create arrays [files name] from folder?

Comment: Yes please provide full code i don't now how to...  #jakecfc1992

Comment: @Foxpro i have answered to your question,please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

I have taken database folder,in this folder 4 files are there,so printed that files names as array.

**Code:-**

```
<?php
$dir    = '/work/database';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
  Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => logo.png [3] => logos.jpg [4] => nbc_logo.jpg [5] => sciit_logo.png )
```

Comment: I want to do like this `<?php
$data = array(
    "Great Bittern" => "Botaurus stellaris",  );  ?>` Ex -  `<?php
$data = array(
    //image_name  );  ?>` . how to? is possible?

Comment: Above code is satisfied your requirement right? output is came as you expected.

Comment: if you want like that just remove "echo "Array Type:".'<pre>';"  and "echo '</pre>';" these two lines.

Comment: Now check the answer,that is as you expected.

Comment: Thank you bro... i poor in php but i want to know Will it work without array i mean [replace array?]  Normaly array - `<?php $data = array( //image_name ); ?>` . Your example `<?php $dir    = '/folder';
$files1 = scandir($dir); ?>` ?

Comment: Is possible to do like this?  <?php $dir = '/folder'; $files1 = array($dir); ?>  ?

Comment: no,not possible,it will print only $dir values(/folder).

Answer (score 0):

As per your question what i have understood that you want names of all images in your particular folder best way to get the list of all images in a directory is to use `glob()` function in php.

```
$images = glob('/youfolderpath/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
//images has all your image names will jpeg, gif and png format, $images is an array that contains all your image names
```

Helpful link:http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp

Comment: Will it work without array i mean [replace array?] `<?php $data = array( //image_name ); ?>` to `<?php $data = glob('/youfolderpath/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE); ?>`

Comment: yes you just need to give the folder name, it will scan all the images in that folder using the extensions that are specified in the parameter

Comment: also remember that using this function you do not get any extra data in the array, exactly the required data only comes in the array

Comment: You already accepted the answer so i think you have a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use scandir() function.
More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php